# SQL, functioning of "select (ALIAS - somevalue) from table, (select max(someotherval) ALIAS from table);"?

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I probably looked for this in the wrong way, but here's one thing I don't understand:

```
select max(dateofbirth) -5 from person;
```

So this example above gives me the maximum date for any person minus 5 days, ONCE as I would expect.

```
select maxpersons - 5 from person, (select max(person) maxpersons from person);`
```

However this other one gives me the same value - just once for every row there is. I know this example is stupid, but for me it's just important to understand the working of this second select clause after the "from table". Does this count as a subselect?

Any help is appreciated, I have my final attempt at the exam tomorrow!

Thanks!

BR Dave

Answer (score 0):

What you do is a select from person and from the result after (,). I assume you get a doubled resultset. One from person and one from maxperson as well. What happens if you execute these two selects seperately? Compare the resultsets.